# How can I get the disk IO trace with actual input values?

Tags: disk-io, blktrace

I want to generate some trace file from disk IO, but the problem is I need the **actual input data** along with timestamp, logical address and access block size, etc.

I've been trying to solve the problem by using the "**blktrace | blkparse**" with "**iozone**" on the ubuntu VirtualBox environment, but it seems not working.

There is an option in blkparse for setting the output format to show the packet data, -f "%P", but it dose not print anything.

below is the command that i use:

```
$> sudo blktrace -a issue -d /dev/sda -o - | blkparse -i - -o ./temp/blktrace.sda.iozone -f "%-12C\t\t%p\t%d\t%S:%n:%N\t\t%P\n"
$> iozone -w -e -s 16M -f ./mnt/iozone.dummy -i 0
```

In the printing format "%-12C\t\t%p\t%d\t%S:%n:%N\t\t%P\n", all other things are printed well, but the "%P" is not printed at all.

Is there anyone who knows why the packet data is not displayed? 
OR anyone who knows other way to get the disk IO packet data with actual input value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know `blktrace` does not capture the actual data. It just capture the metadata. One way to capture real data is to write your own kernel module. Some students at FIU.edu did that in this paper: 
`"I/O deduplication: Utilizing content similarity to ..."`

I would ask this question in linux-btrace mailing list as well: 
http://vger.kernel.org/majordomo-info.html